# Adding GetInt64/SetInt64 to ASP.NET Core Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I need to add `GetInt64` and `SetInt64` instructions to the `ISession` interface in ASP.NET Core so we're able to store some `long` values.

The existing code for `GetInt32` and `SetInt32` is available on [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Http/Http.Extensions/src/SessionExtensions.cs) in `SessionExtensions.cs`.

I am trying to understand the pattern that is in use:

```
    public static void SetInt32(this ISession session, string key, int value)
    {
        var bytes = new byte[]
        {
            (byte)(value >> 24),
            (byte)(0xFF & (value >> 16)),
            (byte)(0xFF & (value >> 8)),
            (byte)(0xFF & value)
        };
        session.Set(key, bytes);
    }

    public static int? GetInt32(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var data = session.Get(key);
        if (data == null || data.Length < 4)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return data[0] << 24 | data[1] << 16 | data[2] << 8 | data[3];
    }
```

I had expected to see BitConverter.GetBytes, but for whatever reason the set is doing a bunch of right shifts against each octet, and the read does left shifts against each octet. I'm guessing that this relates to keeping the endianness neutral as the `BitConverter` methods return different values depending on the CPU architecture in use.

Is there an obvious reason the code is written like this?

Would the following be a correct implementation for SetInt64/GetInt64?

```
    public static void SetInt64(this ISession session, string key, long value)
    {
        var bytes = new byte[]
        {
            (byte)(value >> 56),
            (byte)(0xFF & (value >> 48)),
            (byte)(0xFF & (value >> 40)),
            (byte)(0xFF & (value >> 32)),
            (byte)(0xFF & (value >> 24)),
            (byte)(0xFF & (value >> 16)),
            (byte)(0xFF & (value >> 8)),
            (byte)(0xFF & value)
        };
        session.Set(key, bytes);
    }

    public static long? GetInt64(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var data = session.Get(key);
        if (data == null || data.Length < 8)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return data[0] << 56 | data[1] << 48 | data[2] << 40 | data[3] << 32 | data[4] << 24 | data[5] << 16 | data[6] << 8 | data[7];
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost right. The only problem is that in `GetInt64` you need to cast `byte` to `long` before shifting it.

```
public static void SetInt64(this ISession session, string key, long value)
{
    var bytes = new byte[]
    {
    (byte)(value >> 56),
    (byte)(0xFF & (value >> 48)),
    (byte)(0xFF & (value >> 40)),
    (byte)(0xFF & (value >> 32)),
    (byte)(0xFF & (value >> 24)),
    (byte)(0xFF & (value >> 16)),
    (byte)(0xFF & (value >> 8)),
    (byte)(0xFF & value)
    };
    session.Set(key, bytes);
}

public static long? GetInt64(this ISession session, string key)
{
    var data = session.Get(key);
    if (data == null || data.Length < 8)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return (long)data[0] << 56 | (long)data[1] << 48 | (long)data[2] << 40 | (long)data[3] << 32 | (long)data[4] << 24 | (long)data[5] << 16 | (long)data[6] << 8 | (long)data[7];
}
```

Eventually this code and `BitConverter` has the same result. `BitConverter` is using `Unsafe` to do this operation, maybe that's the reason it's not being used.
https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/BitConverter.cs,107

**Why the shifting?**

Let's say you want to store **472** (a 3 digit number) in one digit place holders. This is what you do.

1. Take the first digit from right and put it in first place holder.
2. Shift the number **one** digit to the right and repeat the first step.

So it goes

**472**  ---> **2**

**047**  ---> **7**

**004**  ---> **4**

This is exactly what's happening here except place holder is a `byte` which holds 8 bits and that is why the shifting is happening 8 bits at a time.

Comment: Thanks. Are you able to shine some light as to why the rotation is happening, and why BitConverter might not be being used?